# Would False Façade be considered an oxymoron such as Act Natural

Tags: oxymoron

I'm using the term False Façade, would this be considered an oxymoron such as Act Natural?

Comment: You maybe perhaps seek the term *[pleonasm](http://literarydevices.net/pleonasm/)*.

Answer (score 1):

Not so much an oxymoron as a redundancy.  A Façade is "false" by definition.

Comment: "A facade is 'false' by definition."  I don't think that's true.  The doors, windows, and trimwork on my house are very real.